# Which power of $2$ kills $W(k)$?

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, quadratic-forms

Is the following fact "well-known": if $-1$ is a sum of squares in a field $k$, then the Witt group $W(k)$ of quadratic forms is killed by multiplication by $2^N$ for some $N\ge 0$? What can one say about the minimal possible $N$ here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking about the exponent of the additive group of the Witt group of $k$.
The answer is two times the level of $k$.

It suffices to show for the forms of dimension one.
If $s$ is the level of $k$, i.e., $s=min\{n\ :-1=x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2, x_i\in k\}$ then every element of $W(k)$ is killed by $2s$. In fact as $s\times\langle1\rangle$ is anisotropic, the order of $\langle1\rangle$ is exactly $2s$. Also with same argument for every $a\in k^\times$, the order of $\langle a\rangle$ is at most $2s$.

This result is due to Albrecht Pfister
(Quadratische Formen in beliebigen Körpern.
Invent. Math. 1,  1966 116–132).

Comment: And the level is always a power of $2$?

Comment: Yes of course, this result is also in the same paper.